# Bounding an infinite sum involving Bessel functions $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{in\phi}J_n(x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, mathematical-physics, bessel-functions, upper-lower-bounds

### Question:

I came across this sum:

$$f\left(\phi,x\right)\equiv \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{in\phi}J_n(x)$$
where $\phi$ and $x$ are real numbers. We know that $f(0,x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty J_n(x)=1$.

Because $\left|e^{in\phi}\right|\le 1$, I was hoping to be able to prove an upper-bound, something of the form:

$$\left|f\left(\phi,x\right)\right|\overset ?\le 1$$
or
$$\left|f\left(\phi,x\right)\right|\overset ?\le g(\phi,x)$$
where $g(\phi,x)$ has a closed form.

Proving bounds for the odd and even sums would also be useful for me:

$$O\left(\phi,x\right)\equiv\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{i(2n-1)\phi}J_{2n-1}(x)\\
E\left(\phi,x\right)\equiv\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{i2n\phi}J_{2n}(x)\\
$$
$$\Rightarrow\left|O(0,x)\right|\overset ? \le1 \& \left|E(0,x)\right| \overset ? \le 1
$$

Any help is appreciated.

---

### Some Background:

This series happens to arise when one tries to get a more accurate solution to the two-level harmonically driven system. Historically, people used to approximate the solution to these systems with the [Rotating Wave Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_wave_approximation). However, last year there was a [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1605.08826) giving a more accurate solution, specially for the strongly driven systems. These series arise when one tries to calculate the ground/excited state amplitudes of the system.

Comment: One may use the [generating function for Bessel functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.12.E1) to show that $f(\phi ,x)=\exp(ix\sin\phi )$.

Comment: @PaulEnta Nice! This means I've grown too lazy; I was aware of these generating functions, but I tried the summation with Mathematica and when I didn't get an answer, I just assumed a closed form for the sum doesn't exist! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: It was a pleasure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the [Jacobi-Anger expansion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Jacobi-AngerExpansion.html)
$$ e^{iz\cos\theta}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}i^n J_n(z) e^{in\theta}\tag{1} $$
hence by substituting $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha $ we get
$$ e^{iz\sin\alpha} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} (-1)^n J_n(z) e^{-in\alpha}\tag{2} $$
and by substituing $\varphi=\pi-\alpha$ and $z=x$ we get
$$ f(\varphi,x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}J_n(x) e^{in\varphi} = \color{red}{\large e^{ix\sin\varphi}}\tag{3} $$
from which $\left|f(\varphi,x)\right|=1$ for any $x,\varphi\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The $O(\phi,x)$ and $E (\phi,x)$ happen to be $i \sin(x\sin(\phi))$ and $\cos(x\sin(\phi))$ respectively, which is pretty neat!